# Play youtube video with video.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, youtube-api, video.js

Have some nodejs app that displays video, but all the time a loader and the video does not play. What am I doing wrong?

update:
This issue only in Chrome

https://jsfiddle.net/x60hksed/

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video-js.css" />
</head>
<body>

<video
        id="vid1"
        class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
        controls
        autoplay
        width="640" height="264"
        data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ"}] }'
>
</video>

<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-youtube/2.6.1/Youtube.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried another browser or disabling extensions (eg. adblockers)? I have clicked your fiddle and the video works for me.

Comment: Indeed! The video works fine form too (Firefox 83).

Comment: sorry, only in Chrome

Comment: Works for me in Chrome

Comment: @misterben Chrome version? are you loged in google?

Answer (score 0):

Use "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-youtube/2.6.1/Youtube.js". For some reason the file .min.js is bugged

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33008562)